# Exclude multiple models from run

Tags: dbt

When running dbt with descendants, I would like to exclude two models. I can exclude one model like so:

```
dbt run ga4_update_set+ --exclude nz_daily_cohorts
```

The above works as expected.

I tried the following to exclude multiple models.

```
dbt run ga4_update_set+ --exclude nz_daily_cohorts,growth_scorecard
```

In this case neither nz_daily_cohorts nor growth_scorecard were excluded.

Then tried:

```
dbt run ga4_update_set+ --exclude nz_daily_cohorts --exclude growth_scorecard
```

Again, in this case neither nz_daily_cohorts nor growth_scorecard were excluded.

How can I run `dbt run ga4_update_set+` but also exclude both `nz_daily_cohorts` and `growth_scorecard`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just space-delimit your exclude list instead of comma-delimiting

`dbt run ga4_update_set+ --exclude nz_daily_cohorts growth_scorecard`

If you need to repeat this job, it may be more convenient to create a selector:

```
selectors:
  - name: custom_job
    definition:
      union:
        - method: fqn
          value: ga4_update_set
          children: true
        - exclude:
            - method: fqn
              value: nz_daily_cohorts
            - method: fqn
              value: growth_scorecard
```

Then run your command with `dbt run --selector custom_job`