# Unable to exclude collections when extracting Metabase exposures

Tags: dbt, metabase, exposure

I am trying to perform exposure extraction from my dbt models. I am following [this example](https://github.com/gouline/dbt-metabase#exposure-extraction). My exposure file is being generated but I want to exclude some collections from Metabase. This is my current code:

```
dbt-metabase exposures \
    --dbt_manifest_path ./target/manifest.json \
    --dbt_database {db name} \
    --metabase_host metabase.{myhost}.com \
    --metabase_user {myuser}@{domain}.com \
    --metabase_password {my password} \
    --metabase_database {db name} \
    --output_path ./models/ \
    --output_name metabase_exposures \
    --collection_excludes 'Our analytics', ABI-queries_SiHay_DEPRECATED, Dashboards_2-1_DEPRECATED, Old _KiWi_DEPRECATED, x_Dashboards_2-0_DEPRECATED
```

When running that block of code everything seems to work but it's not really excluding those collections.

Comment: I think this applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75600390/exclude-multiple-models-from-run/75607081#75607081

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude multiple models from run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75600390/exclude-multiple-models-from-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. The error it's in the commas. The `--collection_excludes` command receives a list and that's why I was using the commas but are not required. The final code should looks like this:

```
dbt-metabase exposures \
    --dbt_manifest_path ./target/manifest.json \
    --dbt_database {db name} \
    --metabase_host metabase.{myhost}.com \
    --metabase_user {myuser}@{domain}.com \
    --metabase_password {my password} \
    --metabase_database {db name} \
    --output_path ./models/ \
    --output_name metabase_exposures \
    --collection_excludes 'Our analytics' ABI-queries_SiHay_DEPRECATED Dashboards_2-1_DEPRECATED Old_KiWi_DEPRECATED x_Dashboards_2-0_DEPRECATED
```